# How do I create a textchange event for WebBrowser control in an UserControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, webbrowser-control, textchanged

I'm using `WebBrowser` control to show/edit body content from an email. All of this I did in an UserControl.

I was looking for on events of designer and `WebBrowser` doesn't have `WebBrowser.TextChange` method. I'd like write on it a method to detect the number of characters that user's typing. (ONLY TEXT, ignore images, etc...)

Answer (score 1):

`System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser` has not text property, so it has not TextChanged event. If you really want to do this, you may try KeyDwon or KeyUp event to achieve it.

The comment can't paste long code , so i add the code here.

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication2.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
    <WebBrowser Name="wb" TextInput="wb_TextInput" KeyDown="wb_KeyDown" Visibility="Visible"/>
</Grid>
</UserControl>


public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //wb.Navigate("http://www.baidu.com");
        wb.Navigate("http://www.bing.com");
    }

    private void wb_TextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        //not work
    }

    private void wb_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Key.ToString());
        e.Handled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I did it but don't work for me. But when I did in Enter event (focus) worked fine.

Comment: I test the `KeyDown` event use MessageBox and `http://www.baidu.com`, it worked on my computer.

Comment: Could you show your code please?

Comment: I paste the code, you can test it on your computer.